# have to extract data from a word file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I have a peculiar problem in that I have to extract information from a word file. Say for example I have a resume and need to extract `name`, `email address`, `phone no.`, `address`, `university`,`Experience` etc.

Every other person may be having  their resume in a different format.So is there any way by which I can programmatically extract the information I need?

I need this information to fill-up a form for registration.

Comment: Down Voter..Please explain me why did you give minus 1.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the word document to html, with aspose .net.
Then you can use regular expressions to search the word and/or pdf documents.
Or you can use HTMLAgilityPack to parse the created HTML documents, and search for specific sections/paths.

PS: 
If you have a regex for email that's shorter than one page, then the regex is incorrect.
Phone should be manageable, as long as you have to support only one country.
As for name and address, good luck with that.

**Edit:**
Like this

VB.NET:

```
Dim doc As New Aspose.Words.Document("filename.docORdocx")
doc.Save("filename.html", Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Html)
```

C#:

```
Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document("filename.docORdocx");
doc.Save("filename.html", Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Html);
```

The component is here:
http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx

To find out what a valid email address is, read RFC 822:
http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html

Comment: how can i convert word doc to html..I am try to read by System.IO.StreamReader

Comment: @sangram parmar: Added :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if at first you might be attracted by the idea of using Com Interop and Asp.net, don't do it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

That said, it's important to know which version of word are we talking about. Newer formats allow treat them as a zip containing xml files and there are good&free libraries.

http://docx.codeplex.com/